# Can i use 'Not only but also' and 'as well as' in a sentence together?

Tags: conjunctions

Please provide an example if I can use as well as and not only but also in a sentence.

For example

> He was not only a humanist but also a short story writer as well as a novelist.

Comment: Your example sentence is fine.  I'm not sure where your confusion is coming from.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I am asking if I could use 'As well as' and 'not only but also' in one sentence together ?.